# can't run a jar with java 11

Tags: java, console, openjdk-11

I have a compiled jar with version 11, but when I open it nothing happens, and through the command line I get an error: Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
I uninstalled jre 8 so that it would run on 11. [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoJMZ.png) [JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEzDw.png) [Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82uTh.png)

how can I make the console and jar act with java 11?

Comment: bad installation/corrupted installation. Did you try taking jar to another machine where Java11 installer?

Comment: no, I don't have the ability to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Windows Search Bar -> "environment variables"
2. Click on the button "Environment Variables..."
3. Double click the button "Path" under system variables window
4. Create a new variable and select the path to jdk11 and move it to the top of the window(or above the other java versions you have)
5. Tell me if it works! :)

Comment: I moved it to the top and it works, thank you